# How To Remove pre - Fill of UISlider

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uislider

I am having troubles with implementation if UISlider.
everything else is working fine except that when Slider thumb is at its minimum position it should not show minimum track image at all.

Screen shot of my iPad Simulator is as follows :-
[image]

in this picture, the thumb nob is at its minimum position but still it is showing "green minimum Track image" which it shouldn't

is there any way to come around this problem ?

code in my viewDidLoad method is :-

```
SLDR.continuous=NO;

[SLDR setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"U14.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[SLDR setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"U31.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[SLDR setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"U9.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[SLDR setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"U9.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Please tell me what am i missing, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard slider thumbImage sits on top of the slider so it covers min positions. Yours is above so the end is exposed. Try creating a new image, by flipping your max image horizontally. Then add a valueCahnged to the slider like this...

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender{

if (SLDR.value == 0) {
    [SLDR setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"U31-flipped.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [SLDR setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"U14.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope this helps!